# Android Studio - Is there a way to show different text optimized for a smaller screen in a button?

Tags: java, android, c++, string, button

I am an amateur android developer.

In my app I have buttons arranged in a Relative Layout. This is the app running on a Nexus 4. The favorite button text fits nicely. ([App on Nexus 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbPg3.jpg))

What worries me is what it will look like on phones smaller than a Nexus 4.

What I'd like to do is make a different string of text appear on devices that can't fit the "Favorites String" in one line. Probably a string of text that says "Favs" instead of "Favorites". ([App on Nexus One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tS1Da.jpg))

Is there any way to code this into my activity_main.xml or do  I have to create a new xml file designed specificaly for smaller phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest putting the icon above the text to increase room.  Also remember that in different languages an abbreviation may not be possible, and english is a medium length language (expect the russian string to be twice as long, its usually a problem language).

But yes, in general you are going to need multiple designs for different classes of phones.  What looks good on a tablets, phablets, normal phones, and small phones are all different.  Generally you target normal phones, it will look good enough on phablets, and then you redesign for small and tablets.